# How to specify Octopus built-in variable names in an XML configuration file?

Tags: xml, web-config, octopus-deploy

We are testing Octopus Deploy, so we made a sample web.config file that we installed and transform in different environments. web.config transformation and use of custom variable work fine, but I can't get build-in Octopus variables to be substituted. Here's an example of of XML section in web.config:

```
  <appSettings>
    <add key="aspnet:UseTaskFriendlySynchronizationContext" value="true" />
    <add key="environmentTransform" value="" />
    <add key="EnvironmentVariable1" value="$OctopusEnvironmentName" />
    <add key="EnvironmentVariable2" value="$(OctopusEnvironmentName)" />
    <add key="EnvironmentVariable3" value="$(Octopus.Environment.Name)" />
    <add key="EnvironmentVariable4" value="$Octopus.Environment.Name)" />
    <add key="EnvironmentVariable5" value="$OctopusParameters[&quot;Octopus.Environment.Name&quot;]" />
    <add key="MachineVariable1" value="$Octopus.Machine.Name" />
    <add key="MachineVariable2" value="#(Octopus.Machine.Name)" />
    <add key="MachineVariable3" value="#OctopusMachineName" />
    <add key="CustomVariable" value="CustomVariable" />
  </appSettings>
```

And here's web.Dev.config, named after the environment:

```
  <appSettings>
    <add key="environmentTransform" value="Dev" xdt:Transform="SetAttributes" xdt:Locator="Match(key)"/>
  </appSettings>
```

And here's the result:

```
  <appSettings>
    <add key="aspnet:UseTaskFriendlySynchronizationContext" value="true" />
    <add key="environmentTransform" value="Dev" />
    <add key="EnvironmentVariable1" value="$OctopusEnvironmentName" />
    <add key="EnvironmentVariable2" value="$(OctopusEnvironmentName)" />
    <add key="EnvironmentVariable3" value="$(Octopus.Environment.Name)" />
    <add key="EnvironmentVariable4" value="$Octopus.Environment.Name)" />
    <add key="EnvironmentVariable5" value="$OctopusParameters[&quot;Octopus.Environment.Name&quot;]" />
    <add key="MachineVariable1" value="$Octopus.Machine.Name" />
    <add key="MachineVariable2" value="#(Octopus.Machine.Name)" />
    <add key="MachineVariable3" value="#OctopusMachineName" />
    <add key="CustomVariable" value="Value for maeaint01" />
  </appSettings>
```

As you can see, Octopus variables are not replaced. Any idea why?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Octopus's config file variable substitution works only on the setting `key`, not the value. If you create a setting like:

`<add key="Octopus.Environment.Name" value="..." />`

then the `value` will be set at deployment time.

What you're attempting with the other approaches is reasonable of course, but not how Octopus currently works with config files.

We've enhanced our variable substitution processing in 2.0 with a new parser and new capabilities (`#{if ...`, `#{each` and so-on) - your question inspired me to draft up [this proposal](https://github.com/OctopusDeploy/Issues/issues/563) which might address this usage better.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. Now I understand. While this certainly work, I find possibility of replacing a "value" (actually - any) attribute more flexible, so it would be great if it can be implemented. Using Octopus variable name in the "key" attribute drags Octopus variable names in the source code, and I'd rather avoid it.

Comment: Thanks - the suggestion by @Declan McNulty below shows how you can alias an Octopus variable with a custom one. (+1 Declan :))

Comment: Yes, this is how we decided to do it at a present time. Thanks!

Comment: This is implemented in the upcoming Octopus Deploy 2.3 release: http://octopusdeploy.com/blog/variable-substition-in-files

Answer (score 2):

I found that my .config files would not pick up built in variables *or* custom variables.

What you could do is set variable in the octopus dashboard called EnvironmentVariable1 and set it's value to be

```
#{OctopusEnvironmentName}
```

This will then transform the EnvironmentVariable1 node in your config to be the environment name that you are currently deploying to.

Comment: Thank you for your suggestion. Yes, it's a workaround, however it would be nice to use Octopus variables in a straightforward way.

Comment: Were you able to get your custom variables to work directly in the web.config?

Comment: Well they are in web.config. Other variables work, but not built-in Octopus.